# Infinite file watcher

Tags: dart

Hello I'm trying to implement file watcher in Dart. And the problem is that I can't figure out how to make forever lister for stream. In my code `print` statement fires only once, when file was changed. I tried `while(true){}` but didn't make affect.

```
import "dart:io";


void main(){
  List<String> paths = ['any.dart'];
  paths.forEach((fp){
    File f = new File(fp);
    f.watch().listen((e){
      print(e);
    });
  });
}
```

Dart info: `Dart VM version: 1.4.0 (Tue May 20 04:56:35 2014) on "linux_x64"`

Comment: Where did you place the while true loop?

Comment: I tried different cases: before ```forEach```, around the ```watch``` function

Comment: It might be platform dependent problem. I can't make it work on Windows 7 with/without administrator privileges for the Dart VM. Someone should test it on another platform.

Comment: Take a look at the http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/watcher package it tries to resolve the platform problems.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look into the doc of the watch function:

```
The implementation uses platform-dependent event-based APIs for receiving file-system notifications, thus behavior depends on the platform. 

* Windows: Uses ReadDirectoryChangesW. The implementation only 
    supports watching directories. Recursive watching is supported.

* `Linux`: Uses `inotify`. The implementation supports watching both 
    files and directories. Recursive watching is not supported.
    Note: When watching files directly, delete events might not happen
    as expected.

* `Mac OS`: Uses `FSEvents`. The implementation supports watching both 
    files and directories. Recursive watching is supported.
```

This means this won't work on Windows. For you problem it says:

```
The returned value is an endless broadcast [Stream], that only stops when
one of the following happends:

  * The [Stream] is canceled, e.g. by calling `cancel` on the
     [StreamSubscription].
  * The [FileSystemEntity] being watches, is deleted.
```

This means either your file got deleted, the stream got canceled or this is a bug and you should file a ticket for this.

On Windows there is no reaction for me. On Mac I get this with your code:

```
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
FileSystemModifyEvent('test_file_watcher.dart', contentChanged=true)
```

How do you test your code? I simple edited and saved my file. So it's working great for me. Which version are you using?

Regards
Robert

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

```dart
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  var fileName = 'test.txt';
  var file = new File(fileName);
  var dir = file.parent;
  var flag = true;
  dir.watch().listen((e) {
    if(e is FileSystemModifyEvent){
      if (e.path.endsWith(fileName) && (flag = !flag))
        print("do something");
    }
    else{
      if (e.path.endsWith(fileName))
        print("do something");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My final version is(inspired by JAre)

```
import "dart:io";


void main(){
  List<String> paths = ['main.dart'];
  paths.forEach((fp){
      File f = new File(fp);
      f.parent.watch().listen((e){
        if(e is FileSystemMoveEvent && e.destination == fp){
           print('Modified with temp file');
        }
        if(e is FileSystemModifyEvent  && e.path == fp){
           print('Modified in place');
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Updated according to the JAre's comment

Comment: Hm, yes, but it seems this problem also editor dependent.
Some of editors(Westorm, Sublime) don't modify file, they create temp file, modify it and rename to origin. So, this solution may covers only one side of problem.

Comment: `e.path` might be relative or absolute.

Comment: It'll the same as in `paths` list.

Comment: it's platform dependent.