# How to auto run transformer on asset change

Tags: dart, windows-7-x64, watch, dart-pub

[Barback package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barback) description:

> An asset build system. Given a set of input files and a set of
>   transformations (think compilers, preprocessors and the like), will
>   automatically apply the appropriate transforms and generate output
>   files. **When inputs are modified, automatically runs the transforms
>   that are affected.** Runs transforms asynchronously and in parallel when
>   possible to maximize responsiveness.

[Docs on assets and transformers say:](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html)

> For pub serve, the transformers run when the dev server starts up and
>   whenever a source asset changes. The pub build command runs the
>   transformers once and then exits.

[So I took this example:](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/tree/master/dart/pkg/barback/example/markdown_converter)

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:barback/barback.dart';
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart';

import 'dart:async';

class ConvertMarkdown extends Transformer {

  // A constructor named "asPlugin" is required. It can be empty, but
  // it must be present. It is how pub determines that you want this
  // class to be publicly available as a loadable transformer plugin.
  ConvertMarkdown.asPlugin();

  // Any markdown file with one of the following extensions is
  // converted to HTML.
  String get allowedExtensions => ".md .markdown .mdown";

  Future apply(Transform transform) {
    return transform.primaryInput.readAsString().then((content) {

      // The extension of the output is changed to ".html".
      var id = transform.primaryInput.id.changeExtension(".html");

      String newContent = "<html><body>"
                        + markdownToHtml(content)
                        + "</body></html>";
      transform.addOutput(new Asset.fromString(id, newContent));
    });
  }
}
```

It runs as expected with `pub build`, but does nothing with `pub serve` except printing:

> Build completed successfully

every time I change any file (not only appropriate asset) in the directory.

[After reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076347/infinite-file-watcher/24078858) I think that Dart has some problems with watching files(not only directories) on Windows platform.

Comment: pub serve should work on Windows, I use it with custom transformers all day. What do you expect to happen with pub serve? No files are changed on your disk - it is a dev server so you have to request your file whit a browser.

Comment: @Fox32 I expect that my transformer will run each time i modify asset. In this case one of  `.md .markdown .mdown` files. But it doesn't. `Pub serve` works fine except it doesn't run transformers in "watch" mode. Probably i misunderstood something

Comment: If it outputs "Build completed successfully" than your transformer was run, but it doesn't write any file to disk, they are only accessible via the build in HTTP server.

Comment: @Fox32 Thanks! I finally got it. Might be you should post answer? I'm not sure that I'm the stupidest person in the World - it could help someone with the same problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that `pub serve` runs transformers after each file modification. But compared to pub build it is not outputting the results to the `build/` folder. `pub serve` is a development server, so you need to request you assets via HTTP, for example in a browser.

See the [`pub serve`](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-serve.html) documentation for more details